# How to add elements to a C# list from MATLAB?

Tags: c#, matlab

I have created a list with five `Int32` integers in Matlab:

```
genType = NET.GenericClass('System.Collections.Generic.List',...
                                                      'System.Int32'); 
arr = NET.createArray(genType, 5)
```

Now I don't know how to add elements to the list.

I tried and failed using:

```
arr.SetValue(1)
arr.SetValue(1,1)
arr.SetValue(1,1,1,1)
arr(1)=1
```

...etc.

Comment: What fails? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following code, it should help you get started:

```
list = NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',...
  {'System.Int32'},100);
list.Add(5)
list.Add(6)

for i = 0:list.Count - 1
   disp(list.Item(i))
end
```

Comment: @timoftebogdan You were creating a generic interface class and the methods were not accessible by MATLAB.

Comment: is there a way to create a .NET list of Matlab structs ?

Comment: @timoftebogdan You might be able to the box the Matlab structure into a  list of type `System.Object` and then unbox it later. Though, I am not certain.